# Ranking a list of emails' Priority

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, ranking

I am trying to produce a simple email ranking program (something like a priority inbox) in Python. Based on the frequency of emails received from senders, so for example have a training set of say 50%, where the frequency of senders is counted and then a test set of 50% which is ranked in order based on the training (so an email from a sender who sends lots of messages is ranked highly).

I have written some Python code to take emails and extract the 'From' address from each. I have placed this information in a list which shows the most common email senders (example snippet from this list below).

```
 //(Email address, frequency of emails received from this sender)//Not Code
 ('tester1@csmining.org', 244)
 ('tester2@csmining.org', 162)
 ('tester3@csmining.org', 154)
 ('tester4@csmining.org', 75)
 ('tester5@csmining.org', 50)
```

I am aware that a number of machine learning algorithms can be used effectively to train and test my data to do what i require. However, i am unsure which of these i can use to give me the best results?

Comment: Where does the machine learning come in if you just want to rank the emails based on the sender frequency? Can't you work this out directly?

Also - are you sure this is a good way of doing the ranking? If a sender is regularly sending emails, one of theirs is likely to be near the top anyway, and there are obvious problems of spammers and the fact that you're ignoring what emails the user prefers to read.

Comment: Well i would like to use a learning algorithm to classify the TEST emails as either important or not important using the TRAINING emails as the learning content. Perhaps using senders is not the best way to do this.

Comment: Perhaps this is more text classification?

Comment: For a supervised learning algorithm, your training data should be representative of the test set. So if you are saying that you want to select your test set based on the sender frequency this is also going to lead to problems. As far as ranking (i.e. regression) vs classification goes, it depends on whether you want to classify emails as *important* vs *not important* or find a way to order them (regression). [This](https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36955.pdf) is a paper describing Google's Priority Inbox.

Comment: Thank you for your input Mr E. This has made it a lot clearer in my head. I am trying to classify emails as important vs not important. The google paper is informative, but is far too complicated for my limited understanding of python to implement. Is there any simpler way to achieve what they have?

Comment: Hey - looks like other people have given some good answers. It looks like you need to do some reading so that you best to know the standard machine learning techniques (eg logistic regression, SVMs) and how to set up your data. You don't necessarily need to know the mathematics behind everything, but it is important to know which algorithms are appropriate in which cases. You will find good implementations in Scipy and Scikit Learn. Sorry this is a bit vague but I'm sure you will get something good going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranking only based on sender is never a good idea. For myself, I subscribe email notifications from github commit. Everyday, I receive hundreds of emails due to my co-worker's code commits.

This is never an easy problem, even Gmail priority inbox does not do well from my experience. A good email priority ranking or scoring system needs good features. I will suggest following features to start with. See [The Learning Behind Gmail Priority Inbox](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36955.pdf):

- Social features. Sender or sender domain;
- Thread feature. Is this email in an active thread? What is the sequence number of this email in the thread? Who are the cc'ed users if any?
- Time feature. When was this email received? If you have access to the owner's reply, you might want to keep track of how long it takes the owner to reply.
- Content feature. This is the bag-of-words model used in spam filtering.
- Behavior. This is how the email account owner responses to the email. Is it replied? or never read? or immediately deleted? or archived to different folders? tagged? If it is replied, you might want to do some content analysis as well. The length of the reply might also be a good feature.

For the regression model, Gmail uses linear logistic regression to keep learning and prediction scalable.

Last as what Gmail does, you can ask the users to help you to improve the system by giving them an option to mark important emails.

Further readings:

- [Understanding Email Use: Predicting Action on a Message](http://sfussell.hci.cornell.edu/pubs/Manuscripts/Dabbish_CHI2005.pdf)
- [The Learning Behind Gmail Priority Inbox](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36955.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to classify an email as important or not important. So first you have to actually manually label each email you have as either important or not important. Then you need to define the features of each email and extract them. In your case the one feature you want to consider is the sender. So you will end up with data like:

`('tester1@csmining.org', important)

('tester1@csmining.org', normal)

('tester1@csmining.org', important)

('tester1@csmining.org', normal)

('tester1@csmining.org', normal)

('tester2@csmining.org', normal)

('tester3@csmining.org', important)

('tester4@csmining.org', important)

('tester5@csmining.org', normal)

...`

Then you can apply a learning algorithm like (linear regression, logistic regression, etc.) and you will be able to test the results on your test set.
The problem is that any algorithm will end-up classifying an email from sender X as either important or normal (probably based on the ratio of important/normal messages from that sender in the training set). In order to get more meaningful results you will need to extract more features from your data, like specific words in the messages, time when it was sent, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!. Ok, i think perhaps including 2 data features e.g. specific words in the message body and sender importance. I suppose i could randomly assign normal and important manually at the starT?